# Clearing the Input Val() still leaves a trailing whitespace

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I have an input, and after pressing space i want to clear the input value. So far I've tried the following

```
input.val("").replace(/ /g,"");
input.val("").replace(/\s/g,"");
input.val("");
input.val("").trim();
input.val("").trim().replace(/ /g,"");
input.val("").trim().replace(/\s/g,"");
```

And all of these are still leaving a beginning whitespace character for some reason. Any suggestions?

JSBIN  http://jsbin.com/amorej/1/edit

I'm not positive on what exactly should be done here as the space is set I believe by the charCode being 32 (space) though after the clearing it should still remove all whitespaces...

Comment: What event are you making this modification on? Have you tried [`onkeyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onkeyup?redirect=no)?

Comment: `input.val("").replace(/ /g,"");` makes no sense. When you pass an argument into `val`, you're using it as a setter, and the return value is the jQuery object on which you called it -- which doesn't have a `replace` function.

Comment: Yes I have this on a onkeyup. I am trying to get rid of any whitespace so I've been trying everything Crowder. Elclanrs code works perfectly.not sure why though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(unicode == 32){
  event.preventDefault();
  // rest of code
```